# Monitor Terminal Service Sessions

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, monitoring

I'm looking for tools that allow to monitor Terminal Service sessions under Windows Server 2008 R2. I'd like to see (preferrably in graphical charts) how much time a user spent interacting with applications, how much time the browser was used, how intensely the user interacted overal with the system while logged in and so on.

I already found this software: http://www.nestersoft.com/worktime/

And would like to know whether anyone can suggest alternatives to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Terminal Services Log](http://www.terminalserviceslog.com/) is probably the best product that I've seen out there, but I've never used it so I can't speak from experience.  It's also not cheap.